# Linux Docker port to host port for forwarding

Tags: docker

I have a docker container with IP 172.17.0.3 running on a host with the docker interface docker0 172.17.0.1 and the eth0 interface 192.168.1.2.

How can I send packets to the host's specific port from within the container?

From the Ip 172.17.0.3 i want to send TCP traffic to port 10000 of th host with IP 192.168.1.2. When the host receivs the packets on 10000 they will then be forwarded over SSH (which I have covered already) via `ssh -NL 10000:ip:10000 username@host -v`.

I assume it's not possible to send them directly from within the container over the SSH from the host, tha's why I'd only need a solution for transfering the packets from within the container 172.17.0.3:20000 to the host 192.168.1.2:10000.

Comment: That is very unclear actually.  What do you mean by the `host's specific port` (what IP and port).  What traffic do you want to direct there (coming in to which interface or from which IP)?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: It's still very unclear.  Is the traffic coming from the container or from the Internet?  Does the container have access to the 192.168.1.0/24 network?  Do you have administrator access on the host?

Comment: The traffic is produced by the container and needs to be send to the host. Yes I have root on the host! No, the container does not have direct access to the 192.168.1.0/24 network otherwise i could just send it there...
I need to send it from the "docker network 172.17.0.1/24" to the "host network"

Comment: Communications have an origin and a destination.  Your description does not cover what is the destination of those packets coming from the container.  Is it simply to give them Internet access or something else?

Comment: I first have to send them to the host, where they will be send over SSH to another host. I assumed for this the pachet has to be send first to the host and cannot be directly send over ssh!? I have covered the forwarding of packets from a port on the host to SSH already that's why I didn't mention that

Comment: You still don't mention any destination!  I read your other question and the same problem was present there as well.  You need to clarify what you want to do and not just for us to help you but for you to understand how it works.  You don't go move packets around without very specific details on where they're from and where they're going.  Those will determine the rule to make for the path to follow.

Comment: The destination is the host with IP 192.168.1.2 port 10000 coming from withing the container 172.17.0.3 port 20000
The other question was very broad and covered a lot and not all details could be covered, that's why I asked this specific problem again!